# Computing question: A quadratic which gives primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics, project-euler

This is about Project Euler Problem 27. The question is:

> Considering quadratics of the form $n^2 + an + b$, where $\lvert a \rvert < 1000$ and $\lvert b \rvert < 1000$
>
> Find the product of the coefficients, $a$ and $b$, for the quadratic expression that produces the maximum number of primes for consecutive values of $n$, starting with $n = 0$.

I've solved the problem using a search through the values of $a$ and $b$, and have improved it by reducing the search space considerably, but I don't understand how the following solution works:

[Haskell Code](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/21_to_30)

```
problem_27 = -(2*a-1)*(a^2-a+41)
    where n = 1000
          m = head $ filter (\x->x^2-x+41>n) [1..]
          a = m-1
```

Pseudocode

```
Let n = 1000
Let m = The first i in [1,2..] such that i^2 - i + 41 > n
Let a = m - 1
Then the solution is -(2a - 1)(a^2 - a + 41)
```

Comment: I do not think that this question is off topic. Although I realise that this is not a clear cut-case, I think that it is not about programming, but rather about the maths behind the solution. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15213/10513) for a meta-discussion on this topic. A summary of the linked-to answer is: `"Do I need to know how to program in language X in order to read or to answer this question?" If yes, then it's off topic. If no, then it's *probably* fine.` As the OP is using pseduo-code, then it passes this basic test.